# Rotate $xy=1$ by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ in a negative (clockwise) direction.

Tags: functions, hyperbolic-functions

I was studying hyporbolae for the first time and noticed that $y=\frac{1}{x}$ is a rotated hyperbola. I had seen equations like $y=\frac{1}{x}$ before but never noticed they where hyperbolae.

Anyway using geometry and the general form of a hyperbola, $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, I realised that $xy=1$ is $\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}=1$ which has been rotated clockwise by $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

I tried to rotate $xy=1$ using the rotation matrix: $ \left( \begin{array}{cc} \cos\theta & \sin\theta\\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{array} \right)$

$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} \cos\theta & \sin\theta\\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{cc} x \\ \frac{1}{x}\end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{cc} x'\\ y' \end{array} \right)$$

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}x}=x', -\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}x}=y'$$

I used two methods. The first worked and the second did not. I'd like to know where I'm going wrong with the second approach.

In the first approach I squared both sides of the above equations and then used simultaneous equations to remove the $x$. Then dividing across by $2$ gives the desired result.

Just out of curiosity I tried another method. I first multiplied across both equations by $\sqrt{2}x$ and rearranged to quadratic form: $$x^2-\sqrt{2}x'x+1=0, x^2-\sqrt{2}y'x-1=0$$

I equated the solutions of each to get: $$\frac{\sqrt{2}x' \pm\sqrt{2x'^2-4}}{2}=\frac{-\sqrt{2}y' \pm\sqrt{2y'^2+4}}{2}$$

The $\pm$s are ugly but I figured I could get rid of them through a series of squaring. I tried a few different ways starting with roots on opposite sides, roots on the same side etc. but I can't quite get it through. Should this work or am I going down a dead-end road ?

Ok I got it: $$\frac{\sqrt{2}x \pm\sqrt{2x^2-4}}{2}=\frac{-\sqrt{2}y \pm\sqrt{2y^2+4}}{2}$$ simplifies to  $$\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}=1$$

Comment: You can't get a 4th degree equation by applying a linear transformation to a second degree equation.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Should this work or am I going down a dead-end road ?

Comment: That depends on where you want to get to.

Comment: I want to end up with:
$x^4+y^4−4x^2+4y^2−2x^2y^2+4=0$

Comment: Why? That's not an equation of a hyperbola.

Comment: In general, you can convert the quadratic equation $Ax^2+ Bxy+ Cy^2+ Dx+ Ey+ F= 0$ to the form $A'(x- x_0)\pm B'(y- y_0)^2= C'$ by translating the axes so that the center of the figure is at (0, 0) and rotating so any lines of symmetry are along the axes.

Comment: True but you can't get a non-quadratic equation that way.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Actually, since $x^4+y^4-4x^2+4y^2-2x^2y^2+4 = (x^2 - y^2 - 2)^2$, it's the equation of a "doubled" hyperbola.

Comment: @Quasi that's fine but it is not an affine change of coordinates and I don't see what purpose it serves.

Comment: @MikhailKatz  Certainly, but the OP is doing more than affine changes of coordinates.  They are squaring the equations, which is why they are increasing the degree of the resulting equation.

Comment: I managed to solve it, thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its easier if we keep the variable $y$ around.  Then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
X\\
Y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\pi/4) & -\sin(\pi/4)\\
\sin(\pi/4) & \cos(\pi/4)
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so $X = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} x - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} y$ and $Y = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} x + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} y$.  Inverting this system, we have
$$
x = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} X + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} Y \qquad y = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} X - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} Y
$$
and substituting these expressions into the equation $xy = 1$, we find
\begin{align*}
1 = xy = \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} X + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} Y\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} X - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} Y\right) = \frac{X^2}{2} - \frac{Y^2}{2} \, .
\end{align*}

Just as a note, in general, squaring equations can introduce spurious solutions because the squaring map $a \mapsto a^2$ is not one-to-one.  The degree $4$ formula you are looking for is actually the equation of a "doubled" hyperbola, since
$$
x^4+y^4-4x^2+4y^2-2x^2y^2+4 = (x^2 - y^2 - 2)^2 \, .
$$

Comment: Thanks Quasicoherent, I was wondering about that option but didn't try it, great stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a 4th degree equation by an affine transformation of coordinates.

Comment: $\frac{\pi}{2}$ was a typo. It should be $\frac{\pi}{4}$.